# navigation using keyboard using jquery

Tags: jquery

1.When i use keyboard up arrow it should highlight a move to up row and if i press down arrow the high light should move to down row

2.If i use uparrow or down arrow along with ctrl ,i should be able to multi select.

Here i have wrote code if i keep pressing up arrow it is continuing selecting and down arrow it is deselecting but i want do as what i mentioned above
[http://jsfiddle.net/hKZqS/2/]

Answer (score 1):

```
switch(e.which)
{
    // user presses the "a" key
    case 38:  if(!e.ctrlKey)
                $('tr').removeClass('ui-selected');
              $('tr#'+(clickid-1)).attr('class', 'ui-selected');
              clickid = clickid-1;
              break;    
    // user presses the "s" key
    case 40:  if(!e.ctrlKey)
                $('tr').removeClass('ui-selected');
              $('tr#'+(clickid+1)).attr('class', 'ui-selected');
              clickid = clickid+1;
              break;
}
```

you'll also have to check if clickid is > 0 and < tr count.
http://jsfiddle.net/hKZqS/8/